# MongoDB Error Starting after Copy

Tags: mongodb, segmentation-fault, database

I copied over a database from one computer to another, tried to run an instance on the second computer and point it to the copied database,but keep getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

I am running a command like this:

`bin/mongod --dbpath='data/' --port=12345`

this command works on Machine 1, but produces the

> Segemntation fault (core dumped)

error on the second one.

I checked for running processes by running the following command:

```
ps aux | grep mongodb
```

and found nothing.  I even restarted my computer to make sure that wasn't it and still nothing.

1. What is causing this error?
2. How do I correctly copy over a mongo db for use on a second machine?  From what I read, all indications are that I should be able to simply copy over and point a new instance of mongo to the db.

Edit:

I have checked my libraries to make sure they are up to date.  I also downloaded and successfully ran a fresh copy of mongo on the second machine with no errors/problems.  This to me indicates it's not a dependency missing on the machine.  The fact that the database that is failing out runs on the first PC indicates to me that the database is not corrupted.

I've also seen recommendations to avoid the mongodump and mongorestore commands because it is slow and may take hours to complete after any significant amount of data is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I was using Filezilla to transfer the files.  What was happening was it was automatically converting newline characters to the Windows default style.

What tipped me off was a bash script I created was returning an error saying #!/bin/bash^M did not exist.  The ^M is an indicator that the windows-style newline is attached.

I went in and fixed my filezilla settings, and am no longer having the issue.